# How to make sure every condition is met before completing a php page?

Tags: php

so say I have the php:

```
if(a === x)
{
    echo "a";
}

if(b === y)
{
    echo "b";
}

if(c === z)
{
    echo "c";
}
```

If *a* = x and *b* = y but *c* **doesn't** = z. Is there a way to stop *a* and *b* being "echoed"?

and the same for if *a* = x but *b* **doesn't** = y and *c* = z. Is there a way to stop *a* and *c* being "echoed"?

---

I know that if *a* **doesn't** = x and thus you don't want *b* and *c* to be echoed then you should do:

```
if(a === x)
{
    echo "a";
}else
{
    die();
}

if(b === y)
{
    echo "b";
}

if(c === z)
{
    echo "c";
}
```

But I want to make sure that if one of the 3(*a,b,c*) doesn't equal the corresponding 3(x,y,z) nothing is echoed.

---

I also can't use:

```
if (a == x && b == y && c == z) {
    echo "success";
}
```

as each hypothetical condition is huge (ie a database insert and checking whether a url is working etc...)

With an example of checking whether a url is working:

```
$file_headers = @get_headers("https://www.google.co.uk/");
if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {

}
else {
    echo "Success concerning url";
}
```

and an example of inserting into a database:

```
if($result)
{
    echo "Success concerning inserting information to the database";
}
```

Is there a method on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Whats the context of this? Anyway, just put them inside all together:

```
if($a === 'x' && $b === 'y' && $c === 'z') {
    // satisfied all three conditions, then proceed
} else {
    // if one of them fails, stop the process
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[***Introducing boolean operators:***](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) **and** (`&&`) and **or** (`||`).

```
if(a === x && b === y && c === y) {
    echo "a";
    echo "b";
    echo "c";
} else {
    die();
}
```

Similarly, you could kill the script if any of the conditions are *not* true.

```
if(a !== x || b !== y || c !== z) {
    die();
}

echo "a";
echo "b";
echo "c";
```

---

If you have many booleans (`a === x`) that make your conditional super long and difficult to read, you can always set the booleans to variables:

```
$boolA = a === x;
$boolB = b === y;
$boolC = c === y;
$boolZ = z < 0 || z >= 100 || z === (a + b + c);

if(!$boolA || !$boolB || !$boolC || !$boolZ) {
    die();
}

// success
```

You could also make one or many functions to potentially clean up your code:

```
function isValid() {
    // perform lots of logic
    return true;
}

if(!isValid()) die();

// success
```

---

In the end of the day..the more complex your code gets, the more you should be using [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). There are a lot of [PHP frameworks](http://mashable.com/2014/04/04/php-frameworks-build-applications/) that will help a beginner get started in this mindset.

Since I've been using [Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/quick) recently, I'll use them as an example. First you have a routing file, which takes all requests to your site and dispatches them to certain classes & methods.

```
// Create a filter for checking if a URL is working
Route::filter('urlCheck', function()
{
    $file_headers = @get_headers("https://www.google.co.uk/");
    if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
        // return a 404 page
    }

    // continue with the normal response
});

// Create a route for a basic request to http://example.com/test
Route::get('test', array('before' => 'urlCheck', function() {
    // create page for successful request to GET /test
}));
```

Comment: @Maximilian I added two more sections that may help you out.

Answer (score 1):

> But I want to make sure that if one of the 3(a,b,c) doesn't equal the corresponding 3(x,y,z) nothing is echoed.

is fulfilled by this:

```
if (a == x && b == y && c == z) {
    echo "all match";
}
```